# Error configuring activemq HA with zookeeper

Tags: linux

I am configuring HA activemq with zookeeper. I use one node zookeeper with 3 activemq node, The content of activemq.xml file as below.I am getting error activemq can vote master but on node master port listen so I can read write is not listening.
I also show the log of master node and slave node below

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

   <!-- Allows accessing the server log -->
    <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
          lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </bean>

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                    <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                         slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                         by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                         For more information, see:

                         http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                    -->
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>


        <!--
            The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
            JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
            the JVM. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
        -->
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <!--
            Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
            mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
            For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
        -->
        <persistenceAdapter>
           <!-- <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/> -->
                    <replicatedLevelDB
                            directory="${activemq.data}/leveldb"
                            replicas="3"
                            bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:0"
                            zkAddress="10.84.5.27:2183"
                            hostname="10.84.5.27"
                            zkPath="/activemq/leveldb-stores"
                     />
        </persistenceAdapter>


          <!--
            The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
            use before disabling caching and/or slowing down producers. For more information, see:
            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
          -->
          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <!--
            The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
            clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
        -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>

        <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>

    </broker>

    <!--
        Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos
        The web consoles requires by default login, you can disable this in the jetty.xml file

        Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
    -->
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
<!-- END SNIPPET: example -->
```

Log master node

```
2022-10-06 15:45:19,969 | WARN  | Store update waiting on 1 replica(s) to catch up to log position 0.  | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.MasterLevelDBStore | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-8
2022-10-06 15:45:20,977 | WARN  | Store update waiting on 1 replica(s) to catch up to log position 0.  | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.MasterLevelDBStore | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-8
2022-10-06 15:45:21,989 | WARN  | Store update waiting on 1 replica(s) to catch up to log position 0.  | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.MasterLevelDBStore | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-8
2022-10-06 15:45:22,994 | WARN  | Store update waiting on 1 replica(s) to catch up to log position 0.  | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.MasterLevelDBStore | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-8
2022-10-06 15:45:23,998 | WARN  | Store update waiting on 1 replica(s) to catch up to log position 0.  | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.MasterLevelDBStore | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-8
2022-10-06 15:45:25,002 | WARN  | Store update waiting on 1 replica(s) to catch up to log position 0.  | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.MasterLevelDBStore | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-8
```

Log slave node

```
2022-10-06 15:46:03,321 | WARN  | Unexpected session error: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.SlaveLevelDBStore | hawtdispatch-DEFAULT-1
    2022-10-06 15:46:04,323 | INFO  | Using the pure java LevelDB implementation. | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.LevelDBClient | hawtdispatch-DEFAULT-1
    2022-10-06 15:46:04,325 | INFO  | Attaching to master: tcp://10.84.5.27:37324 | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.SlaveLevelDBStore | hawtdispatch-DEFAULT-1
    2022-10-06 15:46:04,328 | WARN  | Unexpected session error: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.SlaveLevelDBStore | hawtdispatch-DEFAULT-1
    2022-10-06 15:46:05,330 | INFO  | Using the pure java LevelDB implementation. | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.LevelDBClient | hawtdispatch-DEFAULT-1
    2022-10-06 15:46:05,332 | INFO  | Attaching to master: tcp://10.84.5.27:37324 | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.SlaveLevelDBStore | hawtdispatch-DEFAULT-1
    2022-10-06 15:46:05,334 | WARN  | Unexpected session error: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.SlaveLevelDBStore | hawtdispatch-DEFAULT-1
    2022-10-06 15:46:06,337 | INFO  | Using the pure java LevelDB implementation. | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.LevelDBClient | hawtdispatch-DEFAULT-1
    2022-10-06 15:46:06,338 | INFO  | Attaching to master: tcp://10.84.5.27:37324 | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.SlaveLevelDBStore | hawtdispatch-DEFAULT-1
    2022-10-06 15:46:06,345 | WARN  | Unexpected session error: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.SlaveLevelDBStore | hawtdispatch-DEFAULT-1
    2022-10-06 15:46:07,347 | INFO  | Using the pure java LevelDB implementation. | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.LevelDBClient | hawtdispatch-DEFAULT-1
    2022-10-06 15:46:07,348 | INFO  | Attaching to master: tcp://10.84.5.27:37324 | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.SlaveLevelDBStore | hawtdispatch-DEFAULT-1
    2022-10-06 15:46:07,352 | WARN  | Unexpected session error: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.SlaveLevelDBStore | hawtdispatch-DEFAULT-1
    2022-10-06 15:46:08,354 | INFO  | Using the pure java LevelDB implementation. | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.LevelDBClient | hawtdispatch-DEFAULT-1
    2022-10-06 15:46:08,355 | INFO  | Attaching to master: tcp://10.84.5.27:37324 | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.SlaveLevelDBStore | hawtdispatch-DEFAULT-1
    2022-10-06 15:46:08,358 | WARN  | Unexpected session error: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.SlaveLevelDBStore | hawtdispatch-DEFAULT-1
```

Comment: `No route to host` means you have a network issue. Make sure the nodes can contact each other via names and IPs.